# specifying relative file paths in WP with jQuery requests not working

Tags: jquery, html, paths

Why does it seem that WP requires me to utilize the entire and true file path instead of being able to use a relative file path? I know for safety its better not to use a true file path.
In one of my functions, I am specifying a .php file located. Seems no matter what I do, I can not get my function to point to find the file.

The full directory that the php file is in `domain_name/public_html/wp-content/mythemename/assets/php/select-change.php`

A portion of the code that needs to locate my `php` file:

`jQuery.post("assets/php/select-change.php");`
When using the above I get a 404 error and it tells me it can not find the file using - `domain_name.com/page_name/php/select-change.php` . It seems insistent upon putting the page name in there.

Even when I place the `select-change.php` file directly into the same directory that contains the calling `.js file (assets/js)`, then it still cant find it since it is looking for `mydomain_name.com/page_name/select-change.php` which is not the path. Solution?

(ive also tried things like):

```
`jQuery.post("select-change.php");
jQuery.post("../select-change.php");
jQuery.post("/select-change.php");
jQuery.post("php/select-change.php");
jQuery.post("../../select-change.php");`
```

The PHP file:

```
function change_post() {
if($_POST && $_POST['change']){
$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('UPDATE Staff_Connector_Table SET Staff_List_Staff_Member_Id =  "'.$_POST['change'].'" Table_id ='.$tbl_id));
}
}
```

Comment: What happens in select-change.php - what do you need to post to it?

Comment: It is a db update that comes off the button click.

Comment: Can you share it, so we can understand it better?

Comment: added to the above

Comment: You should not be making direct requests to PHP files in your theme, it is extreme bad practice, insecure, and has lots of issues ( such as the problem you're having ). If you want to do things with AJAX, add a REST API endpoint instead. Look into https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/ you'll get a pretty URL to make requests against

Comment: Also, relative URLs are relative to the current URL in the browser, not the location of the file the code runs in

Comment: Thanks. Is this true for files contained outside of the theme folder as well?

Comment: And a follow up to that - what about using a BASE tag? Just as insecure? I know WP operates differently from the rest of the net, but I couldnt find anything about using a base tag as a security issue - https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/718214639669870683/795347757204242452/unknown.png

Comment: WordPress doesn't run operate differently to the rest of the net. It's just a PHP application. If you're adding functionality to it then there's APIs you should use. That's the same when working with any platform. If you're making your own application from scratch, do whatever you want, but in WordPress the proper way to make AJAX requests is to create a REST API endpoint, not directly hitting the file or using a hack like using the base tag.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, it's not necessary to post to a PHP file, it is only required to include ( or require ) files and then use checks and validations to ensure that code is only processed when required.

You simply need to include the PHP file as part of your application - it will process the PHP is the conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks how would this solve the issue of specifying the path? If I am not mistaken you need to specifiy the file path in the `require` or `require_once`, yes?

Comment: require_once( get_template_directory() . '/assets/php/select-change.php' );

Comment: Isnt that a security risk of showing the absolute path out to that point?

Comment: requiring a file does not expose anything, as this is all server-side - PHP tries to find the file and run the code it finds inside - require_once will only allow that file to be included once, no matter how many times it is referenced in the codebase.